# Can't set UIButton target in another class?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I'm trying to build a custom controller to manage a set of UIButtons.

ViewController where buttons are setup and placed:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button1 = UIButton()
    button1.setTitle("Button 1", for: UIControlState.normal)
    button1.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState.normal)
    button1.frame.origin.y = 120
    button1.sizeToFit()
    button1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let button2 = UIButton()
    button2.setTitle("Button 2", for: UIControlState.normal)
    button2.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState.normal)
    button2.frame.origin.y = 160
    button2.sizeToFit()


    let button3 = UIButton()
    button3.setTitle("Button 3", for: UIControlState.normal)
    button3.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState.normal)
    button3.frame.origin.y = 190
    button3.sizeToFit()

    let controller = CustomButtonController(buttons: button1, button2, button3)

    self.view.addSubview(button1)
    self.view.addSubview(button2)
    self.view.addSubview(button3) }
```

CustomButtonController:

```
class CustomButtonController : NSObject {
    init(buttons: UIButton...) {
        super.init()
        for aButton in buttons {
            aButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressed(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        }
    }

    func pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Press received in CustomButtonController")
        //Never gets called
    }
}
```

If I use addTarget method on a button from inside the ViewController, then it works fine. Any idea why we can't add target to a passed UIButton like that? Thanks

Comment: The thing catching my eye is subclassing NSObject. I tend to do two different ways than you, depending on the situation. (1) If I want to create a button and add a target on it's init, I create a *convenience initializer* and pass in both the *target* and *selector*. (2) If I want to pass the fact that a button has been pressed, I bot (a) tag it and (b) use the button's *.sendAction* instead. Maybe one of these ways can work for you.

Comment: The devil is in the details. You need to show the specific sequence of calls that invoke this. Which object is creating whom? Who's calling CustomButtonController? My guess is that you're calling CustomButtonController before the view controller's views have been loaded.

Comment: @DuncanC add init code, don't think theres anything wrong with the button init. Object gets initialized and passed fine, CustomButtonController is running the addTarget() on each button. It's just not calling the selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating your `CustomButtonController` as a local constant in `viewDidLoad`.  As soon as `viewDidLoad` returns, this object is released and so is no longer around to handle the button taps.

You need to declare an instance property to hold the controller instance:

```
var controller: CustomButtonController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button1 = UIButton()
    button1.setTitle("Button 1", for: UIControlState.normal)
    button1.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState.normal)
    button1.frame.origin.y = 120
    button1.sizeToFit()
    button1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let button2 = UIButton()
    button2.setTitle("Button 2", for: UIControlState.normal)
    button2.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState.normal)
    button2.frame.origin.y = 160
    button2.sizeToFit()


    let button3 = UIButton()
    button3.setTitle("Button 3", for: UIControlState.normal)
    button3.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState.normal)
    button3.frame.origin.y = 190
    button3.sizeToFit()

    controller = CustomButtonController(buttons: button1, button2, button3)

    self.view.addSubview(button1)
    self.view.addSubview(button2)
    self.view.addSubview(button3) 
}
```

Comment: Yup, I was about to say the same thing but you beat me to it. (Voted.) If you don't keep a strong reference to your `CustomButtonController` it will get deallocated.